# Distinct value using hashtable

Tags: c#, linq, hashset

I'm doing distinct values when like looping through a list of values or fields.

```
Dictionary<string, int> _ddistinctValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach(string _word in _words) {
 if(!_ddistinctValues.ContainsKey(_word)) {
    _ddistinctValues.Add(_word, 1);
 }
}
```

Is there a better ways to do this without saving the "1" integer value to save space? I'm using hashtable to get distinct values faster. Maybe hash the wordname without the value, just distinct keys? Is there a class in C# that can do this?

It is not a big issue. Just wondering.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use LINQ and call [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) on the list.  You might want to throw the results into another list.

```
var distinctWords = _words.Distinct().ToList();
```

This would internally use a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) to determine uniqueness which would be the collection you'd be interested in.

Comment: curious if you have a link that explains Distinct() makes use of HashSet.

Comment: @Alan: I suppose you could inspect the implementation using Reflector to verify but would that really matter?  How else would you _efficiently_ do this?

Comment: @iefpw: Right.  The `HashSet` is just a set with set semantics.  The items you throw into the set will be unique (WRT the `IEqualityComparer` used).  The dictionary is essentially a set of keys with associated values which is a little more than you really need.  Note that you didn't really have a choice prior to .NET v3.5, the `HashSet<T>` was not available then and the `Dictionary<,>` was your only option for this.

Comment: I don't have a link to offer, but there's a very interesting comparison of HashSet to Distinct in "LINQ TO OBJECTS USING C# 4.0", by Troy Magennis.  It doesn't confirm (or deny) that Distinct uses HashSet internally, but it's the most lucid discussion on HashSet versus Distinct that I've read on the topic to date...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, HashSet is the class for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a `HashSet<string>`.

Comment: Yes; that's why it's called a **hash** set.  It's O(1).